# In Latex typesetting system, I want to write the symbol 'P'. What is the command to write it?

Tags: mathcal

Could you tell me how to write the following P in Latex?

[image]

It is not equal to \mathcal{P} in Latex.

Comment: Note that we only close via Detexify if it can be found directly on Detexify without any major effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a \mathcal{P}. Note that depending on the font used, \mathcal{P} looks different.

If for example you just open a new document on overleaf.com and you edit "\mathcal{P}" into the source code, you will get:

[image]

That looks exactly like the letter that you want.

An minimal example to get this letter is:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{P}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: you don't need any of babel, fontspec and inputenc for this example

Comment: Thank you. Due to the package 'eucal', \mathcal{P} looks different.

Comment: @percusse Yes, you are right. Overleaf at first gave me an error when removing the lines, so I kept them in. But the error was gone when recompiling from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is `\mathcal{}`

```
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{P}$  
\[\mathcal{P}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I correct your LaTeX syntax, however, what is difference between your and DCTLib answer?

Comment: @Zarko.. I didn't noticed DCTLib answer when I posted my answer. Perhaps we posted it at the same time. Sorry about that. His answer look more proper though.